# No template named 'variant' in namespace 'std'

Tags: ios, c++17, objective-c++, std-variant, xcode10.3

In XCode 10.3 I am getting the error message when I try to build -> No template named 'variant' in namespace 'std'

for the lines of code ->

```
#include <variant>
typedef std::variant<int,double,float,const char*,Mat,Scalar,cv::Point,cv::Size> ocvtypes;
```

In Build Settings I have tried setting the C++ Language Dialect and C++ Standard Library to different values including C++ 17 but to no avail.  This worked before in an earlier version of XCode and the code and project have not changed so I am not sure why this is not working?  Also it is finding the variant header file okay.

Comment: Which version of clang are you using? There is a chance an old version is used where `<variant>` hasn't been implemented yet. [here](https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html) the clang implementation status for c++17 is listed, with `variant` listed as available from clang 4.0 onwards.

Comment: And of course `<variant>` will only be available if at least `std=c++17` is used.

Comment: @RomeoValentin This worked before with a previous version of xcode maybe 10.2 I do not remember what version it was so something changed from the previous version to 10.3 I guess.  "Also it is finding the variant header file okay."  So the header file is found okay but std::variant is breaking the build.  I should add this is for a react native library and I got it working in a standalone app but it is breaking in the react native test app build.

Comment: Did you ever crack this? I'm facing the same on linux using gnu libraries and clang 9.0.0-2

Comment: I never cracked this I wound up just not using std::variant.